# Adding http To Website URl

Tags: apache, http

I have a website hosted on an Apache2 server (for this post, it is `example.com`). However, I would like to have the url be in the format `http://example.com`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All websites have `http://` or `https://` at the start of their address to specify that the protocol is *Hypertext Transfer Protocol*.

As long as the address `example.com` resolves to the IP address of your apache server, then `http://example.com` should be your working url.

Comment: Except it ALWAYS redirects to `example.com`. I need the "http://" to be in there, or else an API that I'm using won't work.

Comment: @mkaminsky - can you describe how the API is being consumed?

Comment: It sounds strange that your webserver would redirect you to the same address where you access it. There are multiple causes of a webserver redirect, and it's hard to say without more info. A shot in the dark: Read about "Canonical hostnames" or the RewriteRule here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: I'm using the Google Drive API, which requires a url. However, the url has to start with "http://" or "https://", or else it's not accepted. Therefore, accessing certain parts of the API at `example.com` doesn't work.

Comment: andrels's suggestion didn't work either...it keeps going in a loop